# spark streaming: job hangs at submitting ReceiverTracker

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Some jobs in my spark (1.5.0) streaming application are hang at: `submitJob at ReceiverTracker.scala:557`. The line 557 is quoted below:

```
val future = ssc.sparkContext.submitJob[Receiver[_], Unit, Unit](
    receiverRDD, startReceiverFunc, Seq(0), (_, _) => Unit, ())
```

I find the [SPARK-1975](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1975), and it's suggested that number of cores should be greater than the number of DStream. It is true in my case: 2 receivers, 4 executors with 3 cores each.

Spark executors:
[image]

Spark jobs:
[image]

kafka topic
[image]

What would be the reason that hang the jobs? Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.